# How can I keep playing waveOutWrite() audio when a user switches their playback device on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, waveout

When a user switches their playback device on Windows, my audio playing through `waveOutWrite()` simply stops. Is there a way to make it continue on the other device?

I am using the `WAVE_MAPPER` flag in `waveOutOpen()`.

Here is my WaveOutOpen() code as requested:

```
WAVEFORMATEX waveFormat;

waveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM; // Uncompressed sound format
waveFormat.nChannels = 2;
waveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
waveFormat.nBlockAlign = waveFormat.nChannels * ( waveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8 );
waveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * waveFormat.nBlockAlign;
waveFormat.cbSize = 0;
      
// Open the audio device
MMRESULT mmresult = waveOutOpen( &waveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &waveFormat, DWORD( WaveOutCallback ), (UINT) this, CALLBACK_FUNCTION );

if( mmresult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR )
{
    printf( "Sound card cannot be opened (code %s).\n\n", std::to_string( mmresult ).c_str() );
    return;
}

soundCardOpened = true;
```

**Update:**

After opening the sound card, it keeps calling the callback function, which I've called `WaveOutCallback()`, with the uMsg parameter set to `MM_WOM_DONE`. This is working properly. However, once I switch my sound device to my bluetooth speaker, it stops playing audio and stops calling this callback function as well.

```
void CALLBACK WaveOutCallback( HWAVEOUT hwo, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2 )
{
    printf( "WaveOutCallback %i %i\n", uMsg, rand() );

    if( uMsg != WOM_DONE )
        return;

    // Audio is managed here (includes a call to WaveOutWrite())
    ManageAudio();
}
```

The bluetooth speaker is working using other applications.

**Update 2**

I've read that `waveOutWrite()` sends `WOM_DONE` to the [waveOutProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743869(v=vs.85)) procedure, which is called `WaveOutCallback()` in my code (as shown above).

It seems to me that once I switch the device, the `WOM_DONE` is not called anymore for the last output buffer. Actually, after the last `WOM_DONE` message, the callback does not print a message anymore.

**Update 3**

I might need to move my `waveOutWrite()` call outside of the `waveOutProc()`, as described in the following reference?

> Applications should not call any system-defined functions from inside
> a callback function, except for `EnterCriticalSection`,
> `LeaveCriticalSection`, `midiOutLongMsg`, `midiOutShortMsg`,
> `OutputDebugString`, `PostMessage`, `PostThreadMessage`, `SetEvent`,
> `timeGetSystemTime`, `timeGetTime`, `timeKillEvent`, and `timeSetEvent`.
> Calling other wave functions will cause deadlock.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743869(v=vs.85)

Comment: This automagically 'just works' for me.  This is on Windows 11, what version of Windows are you testing on?

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm testing on Windows 11 as well. When I am playing audio and switch my audio device, it simply stops

Comment: Please show a minimal sample to help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT The sample is added and I also added a little bounty to the question :)

Comment: This is not a reproducing sample, just a small piece of code.

Comment: @SimonMourier Well, excuse me, but a little kindness is appreciated. I posted the code which seemed most relevant to the issue to me. The file to manage the audio is 880 lines of code

Comment: I added a little more: the `WaveOutCallback()` callback, which seems relevant as well. I believe somewhere between `waveOutOpen()` and the callback, it goes wrong already

Comment: I'm just saying that if you want help, you should maximize your chances of getting help.